# Unset environment variables in loop

Tags: python, environment-variables

Today I ran into a problem in Python where I have to unset a lot of environment variables which are matching a certain pattern. Now I'm wondering which would be the pythonic way of doing this. I searched the net for an answer, but I couldn't find a satisfying one.

**UPDATE:**

While I was preparing an example I found the answer by myself. Is there any better way to do this?

```
import os
import re

regex = re.compile(r'^(env_var_)(.*?)$', re.IGNORECASE)
for key in os.environ.keys():
    if regex.match(key):
        del os.environ[key]
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your question be easier to understand if you were to post your code, tell us what it did, and tell us what you wanted it to do.  As it is, I'm having trouble why setting environment variables would be different whether or not they were set inside a loop.

Comment: You can `del` keys from `os.environ`.

Comment: On the topic of what is pythonic, variables names (here, `Regex` and `Key`) should begin with lowercase letters (`regex` and `key`, respectively).

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I adjusted the sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern seems pretty simple to use regex:

```
import os

var_mask = "env_var_"
for key in os.environ.keys():
    if key.lower().startswith(var_mask):
        del os.environ[key]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`os.environ`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ) provides a mapping representing the environment. Deleting from it (using the [`del`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement) statement) will modify the environment.

Comment: Note that this depends on the platform supporting the `os.unsetenv` function.

Comment: True. If it isn't, Python doesn't provide a way to unset environment variables at all. But it's provided by every platform you'll realistically use.